# Get smooth-shaded normals in geometry nodes

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes, smooth

I ahve a geometry node setup with a curve with a circle profile. The profile has only a resolution of 5, as the extra details are not useful when using shade smooth. However, this makes the normals (created by Distribute Points on Faces) to be of low quality, as they are using the low-resolution geometry.

Is there a way to get the interpolated normals, created by smooth-shading to use elsewhere in the system?

[image: normals view]

[image: normals creation]